# How do you implement Related tags functionality as used in Stackoverflow.com?

Tags: algorithm

How do you implement the 'related tags' functionality as used in many websites like our stackoverflow.com and http://tagexplorer.sandbox.yahoo.com/.

Answer (score 10):

My guess is that it is a correlation between which tags are most often used together.

For example:

- Question A tagged with tag1, tag2
- Question B tagged with tag1, tag3
- Question C tagged with tag1, tag2

Then it's natural to assume that tag2 "is related to" tag1.

I would say the best place to learn would be [O'Reilly's Programming Collective Intelligence book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780596529321).

Comment: ok but if you have, suppose, 3 tags on a post you have to correlate each couple let's say (a,b) (b,c) (a,c) = binomial(3,2) = 3. if you have 10 tags you end up with 45 queries, 20 tags it's 190 and so on :]

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways come to mind.  You could just do a quick query to select related tag names:

```
SELECT * FROM tags WHERE tag_name LIKE '%$current_tag%'
```

Another way would be to actually setup your tag table to have a relations field, maybe related IDs separated by commas, but this seems hellish to maintain.

I'm sure someone will come up with a better answer, so I'm quite curious as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not very good at math :-), but sounds like you are looking for the [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation) between two tags. My first instinct would be to set the expected value to 50% (expecting each tag to appear on 50% of the articles - this might be way off), calculate the correlation coefficient of tags in pairs and decide that if the correlation is above a certain value (which you must determine by experimenting), they are related.

Alternatively you might get by using a simple measure like (number of articles they co-appear) / (total number of articles where at least one tag appears).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe s.o. tracks how many time tags come together

1. I insert Q1 with tags A + B so
   relationWeight(A,B) = 1
2. I insert Q2 with tags A + B so
   relationWeight(A,B) = 2
3. Now I delete  Q1 and Q2. I have to
   know the "relationWeight" to
   disassociate tags when relationWeight=0

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
(DataAccessDataContext db = new DataAccessDataContext())
        {
            Repeater1.DataSource = from rt in db.RelatedTags where st.ITEMID == itemid select new TagView() { ID = rt.Tag.ID, NAME = rt.Tag.NAME };
            Repeater1.DataBind();            
        }

///:)
```

Comment: there are max 5 tags! don't forget!